# R: reshaping data frame to long data format with reshape2

Tags: r, reshape2

I am trying to play around with the `mpg` dataset in `ggplot2`, and I would like to convert the wide data format to long data format for the columns **cty** and **hwy**:

**Wide/Original data format**

```
manufacturer model cty hwy class
audi          a4    18  29   compact
audi          a4    21  28   compact
```

to this long data format:

```
manufacturer model variable value class
audi          a4     cty     18   compact
audi          a4     hwy     29   compact
audi          a4     cty     21   compact
audi          a4     hwy     28   compact
```

I tried to use `reshape2` to do this conversion:

```
mpg_long <- melt(mpg, id.vars=c("hwy", "cty"), variable.name="road_type", value.name="efficiency")
```

This does not work for me. I appreciate your help!

Comment: `id.vars` should be `measure.vars` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is a duplicate question, but...

I think you had your `id.vars` mixed up

```
library(reshape2)

melt(mpg, 
    id.vars = c("manufacturer", "model","class"), 
    variable.name = "road_type", 
    value.name = "efficiency")

## or melt(mpg, measure.vars = c("cty","hwy"))

#   manufacturer model   class road_type efficiency
# 1         audi    a4 compact       cty         18
# 2         audi    a4 compact       cty         21
# 3         audi    a4 compact       hwy         29
# 4         audi    a4 compact       hwy         28
```